# 'gi.repository.GObject' object has no attribute 'threads_init' while excuting bundle build by cx_freeze

Tags: python, gobject

I built my application with cx_freeze in python3. When I execute the application, it report that:

```
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.GObject' object has no attribute 'threads_init'
```

As check the code of GObject.py and GLib.py, it is said that threads_init is now obseleted, I try to remove threads_init from GObject.py, but get the same result, problem remain unsolved.
Could anyone give me a hand? Thank you in advanced.